# Ryzen 7: Unable to install Ubuntu (or Debian)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian

Ubuntu crashes on selecting an install option. When selecting recovery mode Ubuntu (17.04 at this point) displays the following error:

```
core perfctr but no constraints; unknown hardware!
```

When selecting install the last line to be displayed before Ubuntu freezes is:

```
AES CTR mode by8 optimization enabled
```

Before that it also says (with CSM disabled):

```
BIOS EDD facility v0.16 2004-Jun-25, 0 devices found
EDD information not available
```

Specs:

```
CPU: Ryzen 7 1800x
GPU: Radeon rx 460
Mainboard: Asus prime x370 pro
M.2 (NVMe): Samsung 960 Pro
```

Really stuck here..

Also when I disable CSM in Bios the 960 pro won't be recognized by it anymore

Comment: I see similar error messages. I somehow managed to run Debian NetInst and installed a barebone system on an M.2 SATA drive, but it won't boot. I wasn't able to run anything else since. I tried Linux Mint 18.1, Ubuntu 17.04, OpenSUSE Tumbleweed and Arch Linux. I am starting to believe I was shipped a broken motherboard (ASUS PRIME B350M-A). I updated the BIOS - nothing. My RAM is runing on 2400 MHz natively.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and after switching to slower RAM (3000 → 24000 MHz) everything worked fine when I installed 17.04. From what I can tell using anything before 17.04 has large problems.

Comment: How did you figure that out?

Answer (score -1):

Edit install boot option with acpi=off, install Ubuntu. After that you need to update your kernel

Comment: Is there a reason acpi must be turned off?  What I know about the acpi table, would seem to indicate, it wouldn't be related to the issue described the author